gpg decryption failed with cipher algorithm CAST5 not found in recipient preferences
I have generated public private key pair with 3072 key length. I am encrypting file, but when i tried to decrypt file i am seeing.
gpg: WARNING: cipher algorithm CAST5 not found in recipient preferences
gpg: encrypted with 3072-bit RSA key, ID A06D5D0B099E1394, created 2024-07-16
"test <test@test.com>"

I have tried to add CAST5 in the gpg.conf file.
personal-digest-preferences SHA256 CAST5
personal-cipher-preferences AES256 CAST5
default-preference-list AES256 AES192 AES CAST5

I am using gpg v2.2.4
